# Wisdom And Theory Behind Muhammad's (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) Marriages With More Than Four Women?

Tags: hadith, sharia, authenticity, islamic-basis, seerah

The Qur'an permits Muslim men to marry up to four women. However, Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam) was given permission in the Qur'an to marry more than four women in Qur'an 33:50. There are many theories for why this permission was only given to Prophet (Sallallahu'alayhiwassalam). One theory is that he was given this permission to make truce between Muslims and enemies of Muslims. **My main question is: is there any evidence from Hadith or Seerah that this theory holds any water?**